# PHP $_POST with variable name

Tags: php, variables, post, wildcard

I have dropdown fields on an event website with variable names so I'm unsure on how to capture the data with $_POST

An example is

```
tkt-slctr-qty-346[]
tkt-slctr-qty-358[]
```

Is there a way to capture the data with $_POST by using wildcards at all?

EDIT: here is the html

```
    <select name="tkt-slctr-qty-346[]" id="ticket-selector-tbl-qty-slct-346-1" class="ticket-selector-tbl-qty-slct">
   <option value="0">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</option>
   <option value="1">&nbsp;1&nbsp;</option>
   <option value="2">&nbsp;2&nbsp;</option>
   <option value="3">&nbsp;3&nbsp;</option>
   <option value="4">&nbsp;4&nbsp;</option>
   <option value="5">&nbsp;5&nbsp;</option>
   <option value="6">&nbsp;6&nbsp;</option>
   <option value="7">&nbsp;7&nbsp;</option>
   <option value="8">&nbsp;8&nbsp;</option>
   <option value="9">&nbsp;9&nbsp;</option>
   <option value="10">&nbsp;10&nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What do you mean? The name is the key to the `$_POST` array...

Comment: I want to capture whatever has been selected in the dropdown menu

Comment: Are they arrays? I'm assuming so based on the brackets?

Comment: Whatever is sent as POST value by the client is populated into the `$_POST` array on the server side. Nothing you can or have to do for that on the server side.

Comment: I have added the html. hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: You probably want `multiple="multiple"` in your `<select>`, assuming you want several options

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having the id as part of the "name" (which will be used as the key in the `$_POST` array, PHP supports using array notation directly:

```
name="tkt-slctr-qty[346]"
name="tkt-slctr-qty[358]"
```

You can then iterate over these under a single key:

```
if (!empty($_POST['tkt-slctr-qty']) && is_array($_POST['tkt-slctr-qty'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['tkt-slctr-qty'] as $id => $qty) {
        // handle each id/qty value
    }
}
```

If you *do* have multiple select boxes for each id as well, append `[]` to each, and create an inner loop:

```
name="tkt-slctr-qty[346][]"

...

name="tkt-slctr-qty[358][]"
```

And then handle it in an inner loop:

```
if (!empty($_POST['tkt-slctr-qty']) && is_array($_POST['tkt-slctr-qty'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['tkt-slctr-qty'] as $id => $qtys) {
        if (is_array($qtys)) {
            foreach ($qtys as $qty) {
                // handle each qty if there are multiple fields.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You changed OPs keys from `tkt-slctr-qty-346[]` to `tkt-slctr-qty[346]`, that won't work.

Comment: @DanFromGermany That was the point - if he changes the keys, he'll get an proper array automagically.

Comment: The arrays are already proper. You assume there is only 1 select field but there are obviously multiple selects.

Comment: You are right tho, it does not make sense to mark a single value field as array with `[]` in the name. The HTML should be fixed first.

Comment: No, that's not the assumption. First, there are obviously multiple select fields - but not necessarily for each id - if that's the case, append `[]` to get an array for each id. The point is that you should move the variable part of the prefix check to a proper array key, and not do any magic prefix matching. PHP have the means to do this properly and express exactly what the poster want to do (even if there are multiple select boxes for each id).

Comment: I've added an extra example with an inner loop in case there are multiple checkboxes for each id as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can get post variables to an array then iterate through it while you filter.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $pos = strpos($key , "tkt-slctr-qty-");
  if ($pos === 0){
    // do something with $value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you submit those arrays, PHP will receive them this way:

```
$_POST['tkt-slctr-qty-358'][0]
$_POST['tkt-slctr-qty-358'][1]
// ...
```

If you mean to capture the numbers at the end of the key dynamically, it works the following:

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if (strpos($k, 'tkt-slctr-qty-') === 0) {
        foreach ($v as $innerValue) {
            echo 'Key: ' . $k . ' has value: ' . $innerValue . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Iterate through the $_POST array holding the collection. Follow the pattern below

```
$counter = count($_POST['tkt-slctr-qty-346']);
    $image = '';
        for($i=0; $i< $counter; $i++)
        {
        $data = $_POST['tkt-slctr-qty-346'][$i];
        //Then Write the code that processes the data here
        }
```